# PHP Accessing And Searching a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, search, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [@attributes] => stdClass Object (
            [Id] => 0 [MapId] => 1 [Name] => [LocationId] => 0 [MapRelativeX] => 0.58813826735513464 [MapRelativeY] => 0.5223214285714286
        )
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [@attributes] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => 1 [MapId] => 1 [Name] => GL D [LocationId] => 1 [MapRelativeX] => 0.54053714859437729 [MapRelativeY] => 0.43601190476190477 ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [@attributes] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => 2 [MapId] => 1 [Name] => GL E [LocationId] => 1 [MapRelativeX] => 0.458028542742398 [MapRelativeY] => 0.5223214285714286 ) )
```

I am trying to access and search through this array. For instance I am trying to access the ID key/value pair but I can't. I have the following code.

$row->Id doesn't return anything where $row is $fullArray[0]

Also is there a way to search this array for the row with the ID=2?

Thanks

Comment: just follow the chain. `$fullarray[0]->@attributes->id`, though this exact string is NOT valid php.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out:

```
$row[0]->attributes()->Id
```

:)